# PHP login to HTTPS page using Curl

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

I am trying to use php curl function to log in to a https webpage "https://portal.opalonline.co.uk/Home/PortalCore/SignIn/SignIn.aspx"

but I have run out of ideas how I can post values to this particular page (username, password) and 'press 'sign in'.

```
$postfields = array('ctl00_MasterContentContentPane_Signin1_userID_txt'=>'email@address.com', 
            'ctl00_MasterContentContentPane_Signin1_password_txt'=>'somepassword123');

/* LOG IN TO TalkTalk ACCOUNT */
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://portal.opalonline.co.uk/Home/PortalCore/SignIn/SignIn.aspx?");   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE); 
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
var_dump($ch);
$string_exec = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($string_exec);
```

I can not even display the page with var_dump :( . Ideas / suggestions much appreciated

Comment: Let's keep it civil.  Maciej Cygan would appreciate a comment if you downvote.

Comment: @JeremyStein Thank you, indeed i would appreciate if someone did provide a reason as to why he is downvoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't think you can do the 'array' thing like that as that will make PHP/CURL create multipart formpost instead, and this is not such a form. Provide the data in "name=value&name2=value2" style.

Then, make sure you also submit all the hidden fields in the form. There are at least four of them. One of them is set by the HTML to a long value that you need to extract and set, and there is also some javascript magic that sets some of the others. You probably need to use your browser's networking tool to snoop on what exactly your browser sends to be able to mimic that perfectly.

The login page sets cookies and you *probably* need to pass those cookies on when you submit the login form. So you need to first fetch (GET) the login form page to get the cookies, then file the login POST.

With that fixed, you should be closer. If that isn't all that takes, then continue comparing the browser's request with what your request is sending and make sure they are as similar as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Open the website in google chrome, open the console, to go the network tab.

Login to the website. You should see the request in the network tab. Do a right click on it, select "copy as cURL". It will give you a command line, that will help you understand what you need.